# Output an Excel file from classic ASP and Office 2010 don't open

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I have an application that generates a classic asp excel file, it has been operating years. A few days ago I see that excel generates doen't open with excel 2010. I have tried from multiple computers and the result is the same. However, the file opens from OpenOffice. I think is a problem with Excel 2010.

I use this sentence:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "inline; filename=test.xls"
```

I have tried too using:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Excel 2010 should be able to open the old format (xls) stylesheets as well as the newer xslx.  It might be worth your while reinstalling Excel

Comment: Would be useful to describe the actual behavior you see - what actually happens when the file is sent?

Comment: Hello, I press a button and the excel file is downloaded. When I click on the file to open, Excel opens but the file don't appear, that is, as if you open the Excel program. 
Thank you!

Comment: @JesúsChicaCáceres did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same issue with customers using Excel 2016.  It seemed to have started after a patch to excel on the 13th.

To get the customers running again we had them turn off "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet" and "Enable Protected View for files located in potentially unsafe locations".

Haven't found a fix for it yet.

Edit:  another better solution I've found is to have the customer add the site to their "Trusted sites".

Comment: How to add a site to "Trusted sites" in Firefox or Chrome ? as far as I know, "Trusted sites" is an Internet Explorer thing ...